# Is there a rational parameter for the cylindrical curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-curves

Is there a rational parameter for the cylindrical curve?
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
x^2-y^2=2\\
y^2-z^2=3
\end{split}
\right.
\end{align*}
It seems to have something to do with the topic of number theory.

**concordant forms**

\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)^2=2\\
\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)^2-\left(\frac{c}{k}\right)^2=3
\end{split}
\right.
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\left\{
\begin{split}
b^2+2k^2=a^2\\
b^2-3k^2=c^2
\end{split}
\right.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**An idea which may be of use for you**

I'm assuming that you are asking if these equations have a rational solution. If not please ignore my answer and I'll delete this post.

The answer to the rational point question is yes! You can quickly check that there is a solution $$x=\frac{9}{4},y=\frac{7}{4},z=\frac{1}{4}.$$

If this is all you require then that's great but going much beyond this does require a lot of relatively advanced number theory so I will await your response before proceeding much further. If you do know some of the theory of elliptic curves, then the fact that I have given you a rational point means that it is now easy to convert the problem into finding solutions of an elliptic curve which can be done online.

Comment: Thank you very much! At the beginning, I felt that it was related to elliptic curve, but I didn't try it later. Can we use the additive property of elliptic curve to get parameterization?

Comment: @D.Matthew There's no rational parameterization, but can you use [℘](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions)?